# Wtforms: How to generate blank value using select fields with dynamic choice values

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, wtforms

I'm using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with WTForms ([doc](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html)) on Google App Engine. What is the best way to generate an field with an empty value for a select field?

```
form.group_id.choices = [(g.key().id(), g.name) for g in Group.all().order('name')]
```

Is there something like "blank=True" for the form field?

```
myfield = wtf.SelectField()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you just prepend an empty pair to the list?

```
form.group_id.choices.insert(0, ('', ''))
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's a `QuerySelectField`, you can add parameters like this:

```
allow_blank=True, blank_text=u'-- please choose --'
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer such a way:

```py
form.group_id.choices = ['none'] + [(g.key().id(), g.name) for g in Group.all().order('name')]
```

and that's enough - you don't need to deal with `'none'` value.