# Trying to insert blank option in dynamic WTForm field

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to add a blank option in an existing working dynamic field (customer) following a result I found on SOF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868718/wtforms-how-to-generate-blank-value-using-select-fields-with-dynamic-choice-val), however getting an error.

The error is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.`

I can provide the full traceback if necessary.

Here is the form - the dynamic field is the customer one as you can see:

```
class FilterWorkorderForm(FlaskForm):
    id = IntegerField('id', validators=[Optional()])
    date = DateField('Date', validators=[Optional()])
    customer = SelectField('Customer', coerce=int, validators=[Optional()])
    customer_po = StringField('Customer PO', validators=[Optional()])
    requested_by = StringField('Requested By', validators=[Optional()])
    work_description = StringField('Work Description', validators=[Optional()])
    status = SelectField('Status', choices=[('Quote', 'Quote'), ('Pending', 'Pending'), ('WIP', 'WIP'), ('Complete', 'Complete'), ('TBI', 'TBI'), ('Invoiced', 'Invoiced'), ('VOID', 'VOID')])
```

Below is the route:

```
@app.route('/reports/filter_workorder', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def filter_workorder():
    results = None
    form = FilterWorkorderForm()
    form.customer.choices = [(cus.id, cus.company_name) for cus in Company.query.order_by('id')]
    ### LINE CAUSING ERROR ### form.customer.choices.insert(0, ("", "")) ### LINE CAUSING ERROR ###
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            try:
                customer_id = form.customer.data
                customer = Company.query.filter_by(id = customer_id).first_or_404()
                customer_name = customer.company_name
                filter_data = {'id' : form.id.data, 'date' : form.date.data, 'customer_po' : form.customer_po.data, 'customer' : customer_name, 
                'work_description' : form.work_description.data, 'status' : form.status.data}
                filter_data = {key: value for (key, value) in filter_data.items() if value}
                results = Workorder.query.filter_by(**filter_data).all()
            except Exception as e:
                db.session.rollback()
                flash(e)
        return render_template('filter_workorder.html', form = form, results = results)
    return render_template('filter_workorder.html', form = form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is rendering your forms, specifically the customer field, with the integer coercion.

According to the [WTForms's documentation on the `Select` widget](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.4/widgets.html#wtforms.widgets.Select):

> The field must provide an `iter_choices()` method which the widget will call on rendering; this method must yield tuples of `(value, label, selected)`.

If you look at [the source code for this method](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/086d0bf7d6d73ab9a05e30b861adee627916a71c/wtforms/fields/core.py#L453-L455):

```py
def iter_choices(self):
    for value, label in self.choices:
        yield (value, label, self.coerce(value) == self.data)
```

There's no exception-handling in this method for failed coercion. In your case, `self.coerce(value)` gets executed as `int('')`, which causes the `ValueError` exception you're encountering.

There are at least two solutions:

1. Remove `coerce`.
2. Use a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) such as `0` or `-1` to represent that no customer is being selected:

   ```
   form.customer.choices.insert(0, (0, ""))
   ```

   This value will pass coercion, but you'll need to handle this value (to unset the "customer" field) post form-processing.

Comment: This is correct! Thank you. I should have been able to figure that out on my own. Just had to adjust my route processing to handle the change. All set.